# What is keeping this option select from working?

Tags: jquery, html-select

You may assume that I have jquery installed. This is a dropdown with images, using Mr. Suleman's plugin msDropdown (www.marghoobsuleman.com) I can't figure out why this doesn't work. Probably a syntax error I'm missing...

```
<select name="websites2" id="websites2" style="width:318px;" tabindex="1">
  <option name="one" value="Free" selected="selected" title="suleman_drpdwn/images/FREEButtonmenu.png">Free Trial</option>
  <option  name="two" value="Flexi" title="suleman_drpdwn/images/FlexiButtonmenu.png">Flexi Plan</option>
  <option name="three" value="Grow" title="suleman_drpdwn/images/GrowButtonmenu.png">Grow Plan</option>
  <option name="four" value="Excel" title="suleman_drpdwn/images/ExcelBtnMenu.png">Excel Plan</option>
  <option name="five" value="Max" title="suleman_drpdwn/images/Maxbuttonmenu.png">Maxi Plan</option>
</select>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("websites2").find("option[value='"+Max+"']").attr("selected", "selected") 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("websites2")
```

should be

```
$("#websites2")
```

What you are doing is looking for an element `<websites2></websites2>` instead of something with that id.  `#` is used for id.

Also, `Max` is not defined anywhere, though I'm assuming you just left that out.

Comment: None of the suggestions here worked.  You pointed out that I don't have "Max" defined.  But I think I do. The code says 'value-"Max"', and that's what I'm askong for.  Here's what I have now in the function:       $('#websites2').find('option[value="Max"]').attr('selected', 'selected')

Comment: The way your code was written originally, you were trying to concatenate a variable named `Max` which you had not defined.  That was what I meant.  The way you have the code now does work.  See @JaredPar's working example.  If it does not work in your code, there is something else going on which was left out of the question.

Comment: I devised a workaround for this.  I'm writing the entire select block with PHP, with the select option set based on the the query string. Its overkill, but it works.  Now I just have a graphics centering problem, which I'll take up in a new question, as it is not releated to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value of the select , jQuery will manage the "selected"

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
 $("#websites2").val( Max)
```

Comment: ok.. in my example Max is a variable which I may have misinterpreted from your code...  if it is a string just pass string in

Comment: I figured that.  Still not working.  Something else is keeping this from happening.  I can see from @JaredPar 's jsfiddle that this method works, and its exactly what I 'm doing.  But it's not working....

Comment: put your code in a fiddle, can't help when what we supply works and yours doesn't unless you show what you are doing

Comment: I put it in the fiddle and it worked.  It also works in IE.  But the plugin DOESN"T work and the dropdown appears to the right of the grpaphics and the page is all screwed up. So, there's something wrong in the plugin, I guess.

Comment: really doesn't help to keep adding comments unless there is something to look at, no idea what plugin you are talking about, if you update fiddle post a link

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `#` in your selector and to set the selected option of select element you can just pass the value to be selected to `val()` method it will select it.

```
$("#websites2").val('Max');//I assume Max is the actual value and not a variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ID selector # on websites2 and use the string constant `Max`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#websites2').find('option[value="Max"]').attr('selected', 'selected') 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FEEMw/

Comment: @I_miss_Steve_already did you try the fiddle? It's working there.